# How to Fire a Method When the Component Changes in Angular

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular

In Angular,

There is a `ngOnInit()` method in component.

I want the opposite of this method. Is there any method when the component is closed ?

Is there a way to catch in its TypeScript file if the component is closed ?

I mean,

```
ExampleComponent.TS

    ngOnInit() {
        // opened component
    }

    ????() {
        // closed component
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ngOnDestroy` is what you need. It's called right before the component has been disposed.

Comment: Thanks. @PampaZiya